# Implemented Rails 3, but "rails -v" is still 2.3.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, version

I can see the rails 3 gem from gem list. But why the rails -v still tell 2.3.10? What should I do to update it?

Comment: Could you give us the result of `gem list`?

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile for your project, just specify :

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
```

And you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of rails showin in `gem list`, you can call a specific one by passing the version as the first argument:

```
$ rails _2.3.5_
```